# Will java heap thrash to disk in this scenario?

Tags: java, jvm

I can see that my heap allocated is 1312MB and used is 1300MB. Do this mean the JVM is thrashing 12MB of memory to disk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used 1300 MB of 1312 MB heap this means it is about to perform a GC to clean up space.

The JVM doesn't swap anything to disk.  This is the job of the operating system and the JVM has no idea if this is happening or not.

BTW: You want to avoid swapping any portion of the heap as the GC assumes random access of the memory.  If you have a GC while the heap is swapped, the machine can become unusable.  In short, always make your heap small enough that it should never swap.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "see" ?

I'm assuming you are looking via jstat, If you are referring to the OC (old generation capacity) and to the OU (usage), than it means that your process is almost consumed all the memory for the old generation section. it means you have only more 12MB free to use (look at the number of full GC, probably it's running every second)